# Core Plot Logarithmic axis and panning

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-plot

I am using a core plot XY Scatter Plot, and I set the plot space scaleType to LOG for logarithmic. When the user zooms, after that, a panning causes the y-axis to scale as well, as if the user was pinching (But only one finger is being used!)

This does not happen if the scaleType is linear.

Is this a feature or a bug?

Any solutions on how to avoid this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Adding callbacks into the space plot delegate, I can see that the displacement vector along the y-axis is not linear when the y-axis scale type is logarithmic. I just can't figure out if this is a feature. I have tried updating to latest core plot 1.2, getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a feature, and this is basic math. It looks like scaling when panning on a LOG scale, because the scale is not linear.

Answer (score 0):

It's working as designed. It shifts the plot area without changing the length. This makes the distance between tick marks change as they move across the plot area.

If you'd like to see an option to scroll differently, please put an enhancement request on the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list) with details.

Eric